# Automated load tests on a WIF-enabled application

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, load-testing, wif

We need to do some performance and load testing on an application that uses Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) for authentication.  Since the tests will need to measure the performance of secured pages, what is the best way to "impersonate" a logged in user?

Should we simply copy and paste an authentication cookie into the request?  Is there a recommended approach to doing this?

We will probably use something like JMeter to do the load testing.

**Update**: It looks like you can record tests in JMeter so that can be used to capture the sign-in request.

http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/jmeter-101-using-http-proxy-to-record-your-test/

Comment: Did you manage to get it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying cookies will probably take you anywhere as WIF authentication cookies expire, just like Forms cookies do.

I do not know JMeter but maybe it can be automated so that legitimate authentication with required redirects to and from the STS takes place? We automate our WIF-powered web apps using one of UI automation based technologies and there are no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  So what are these UI automation based technologies that you use?  I think we may have to figure out a way to handle posting legitimate credentials and managing the redirects, but I don't know how well JMeter deals with that.

Comment: We use the automation framework from Ranorex but any other will do.